# Assigning values to an array of ints through a function in C

Tags: c, function

I am making a weird unpractical program that calls four functions.

First function reads 30 integers to an array;

Second does the same but to another array;

Third should make another array with 60 elements, half being the elements of the first array, other half being the elements of the second array;

Fourth will show the entire array to the user.

I'm stuck on my third function. I am not finding anything explaining how to change the values of an array of integers through a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void array1(int *a1);
void array2(int *a2);
void mash(int *a1, int *a2, int *a);
void exhibit(int *a);

int main()
{
    int a1[30];
    array1(a1);


    int a2[30];
    array2(a2);


    int a[60];
    mash(a1, a2, a);


    exhibit(a);


    return 0;
}


void array1(int *a1)
{
    int temp[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", a1 + i);
    }
}


void array2(int *a2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", a2 + i);
    }
}


void mash(int *a1, int *a2, int *a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        a + i = a1 + i;
    }
}


void exhibit(int *a)
{

}
```

I thought I should be able to access each element by adding 1 to the pointer as I did to get input on my earlier functions.

Comment: Try: `*(a + i) = *(a1 + i);` or better/clearer still: `a[i] = a1[i];`

Comment: You should dereference and assign: `*(a + i) = *(a1 + i)`, also look for `memcpy`.

Comment: Try: `for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++, a++) *a = a1[i]; for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++, a++) *a = a2[i];` Or, instead: `for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) a[i] = a1[i]; for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) a[i + 30] = a2[i];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *access* those pointers, i.e. dereference them like this:

```
*(a + i) = *(a1 + i);
```

To make it less ugly there's syntactic sugar:

```
a[i] = a1[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

To access an element at `index` location of an array, you are doing:

```
*(array + index)
```

this is equivalent to

```
array[index]
```

this also looks more clear and easy to understand.

For getting input elements to array, you are doing

```
scanf("%i", a1 + i);
```

you can also use `&a1[i]` because `&a1[i]` is equivalent to `a1 + i` -

```
&a1[i] --> &(*(a1 + i) --> a1 + i
```

> *Third should make another array with 60 elements, half being the elements of the first array, other half being the elements of the second array*

Your `mash()` should be like this:

```
void mash(int *a1, int *a2, int *a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a1[i];
        a[i + 30] = a2[i];            
    }
}
```

Instead of using numbers like `30` in function, better to pass size of array along with array that you want to iterate in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
void mash(int *a1, int *a2, int *a)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
  {
    a[i]=a1[i];
    a[30+i]=a2[i];
  }
}
```

since you already know the array a have 60 elements and a1 a2 have 30 each , you just need to insert from the start with a1 and from the middle with a2